# Reinforcement Learning, wont learn and bad in test set

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm study and try to understand better the reinforcement learning branch;

In this case I want to learn the agent to make a reward; I've tried with:

- A2C
- DQN
- PPO2

   but the agent in test env make ever the same action, and total profit is negative.
  Which is the problem?

This is my colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HxjONW_QvYPagk7clUrUPFAkpJ59OwZ8?usp=sharing

Comment: As a first suggestion, trying to understand better the RL field and starting from the most advanced and complicated techniques won't really help you even if you understand the code (simply you won't be able to understand the why and why the algo fails). Also the question is too generic. There can be all sorts of things from problem formulation down to details such as a specific hyperpatameter to even a simple bug. Could you describe as an MDP the problem you are trying to solve? Taking a quick look at your code, I have the impression that you might try to solve a regression problem with RL.

Comment: Thanks @Constantinos, My goal is to let the agent learn what are the best actions to take to get the best reward.
For each tick, i.e. each row of the dataset, where a series of data is provided, the agent should learn to do action 0, or action 1.
But in reality on the test dataset, it only ever performs one type of action.
I do not understand why

Comment: As I have guessed most likely you have a bandit problem and you try to solve it with a sequential model. I think you use the dataset features as states and you output an action with your model. One question you need to ask (thats why you need to write down the problem as an MDP): Is the next feature vector dependent on the model's previous action or it will come no matter what? As a note these models are quite advanced and are not intended to work out of the box in a plug-n-play fashion. For example you might need to change the way you calculate the expected reward.